# Can void be used in toString method

Tags: java, methods, tostring

I am creating a program but i want to print the string from toString method directly with using System.our.println(ClassName.toString()),

Instead i want just to write the ClassName.toString(); and it print the output.

Comment: Why not have it return a String, but not assign it to a variable?

Comment: `write the ClassName.toString(); and it print the output.` That's what the code you have written does.

Comment: Why use `toString()` for this? just write a separate method `ClassName.print()` or equivalent instead.

Comment: you cant have your cake & eat it too !!

Answer (score 1):

***No***, because if you want to call `toString` method like `ClassName.toString()`, that means you want to create a `static` toString() method in your `ClassName` class, means you are `hiding` toString instance method of `Object` class with static method of your class, but Java rule says you cannot hide instance methods with static method.

Java Specification reference: [jls 8.4.8.2. Hiding (by Class Methods)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2)

> It is a compile-time error if a static method hides an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` method is a method available in Object class.

any class in java if its not extending any parent class then it will have internally Object class as parent.

and `toString()` method is non final in Object class

so it means we can override the `toString()` method in any of the subclass.

and return type of overridden methods should be same if its built in type and it should be same or parent if its custom object.

so in our case of `toString()` its return type is String so nobody can replace String for return type.

hence changing it will give compile time error.

so to achieve your scenario you can do as below in the worst case

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
    System.out.println("your string");
        return super.toString();
    }
```

and call this method using object of this class, if class name is A

then

```
 A a = new A();
a.toString();
```

will automatically print the content on console using its body.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the other answers have covered “don’t do that”, but this is my “try this instead”. But if you are simply trying to accomplish a more terse way of printing the `toString()` output you could do something like this instead:

```
public class PrintMe {
    private String data = "Just an example";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintMe p = new PrintMe();
        p.print();
    }
}
```

**Output:** `Just an example`